# Does NTFS / Windows as OS performs checksumming on file movement operations by default?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, checksum

That's what I can't find

Does NTFS / Windows as OS performs checksumming on file movement operations by default?

alike ZFS or somehow else...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No NTFS doesn't calculate a checksum.
Take a look at [Does Windows calculate CRCs to check every file operation?](https://superuser.com/questions/566113/does-windows-calculate-crcs-to-check-every-file-operation) and in the [Wikipedia file comparsion table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata)

In the [How NTFS Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) Technet article you will learn how NTFS works.